How to create a QComboBox with checkboxes for multiple selection in PySide6?
I’m trying to create a custom QComboBox in PySide6 that allows multiple selection by adding checkboxes next to each item. The goal is to have the selected items displayed in the placeholder area of the combo box once they are checked.
I've created a custom QComboBox and used a custom delegate (QStyledItemDelegate) to handle rendering the checkboxes. However, I’m facing two issues:

The checkboxes are overlapping with the item text in the combo box drop-down.
The placeholder area (the combo box’s display area) is not updating with the selected items after they are checked.

Code I'm Using:
import sys
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt, QEvent, QTimer
from PySide6.QtGui import QIcon
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QComboBox, QListView, QStyledItemDelegate, QApplication, QStyle, QStyleOptionViewItem, QStyleOptionComboBox, QStylePainter


class CheckComboBox(QComboBox):
    """
    A QComboBox allowing multiple item selection.
    """

    class ComboItemDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
        """
        Helper styled delegate to draw checkboxes and item text properly, avoiding overlap.
        """

        def paint(self, painter, option, index):
            style = option.widget.style() if option.widget is not None else QApplication.style()

            option = QStyleOptionViewItem(option)
            option.showDecorationSelected = True

            # Get the rectangle for the checkbox
            check_rect = style.subElementRect(QStyle.SE_ItemViewItemCheckIndicator, option, None)

            # Adjust the text rectangle so it doesn't overlap with the checkbox
            option.rect.setLeft(check_rect.right() + 5)

            # Draw the item (checkbox + text)
            super(CheckComboBox.ComboItemDelegate, self).paint(painter, option, index)

    def __init__(self, parent=None, placeholderText="", separator=", ", **kwargs):
        super(CheckComboBox, self).__init__(parent, **kwargs)
        self.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)
        self.__popupIsShown = False
        self.__blockMouseReleaseTimer = QTimer(self, singleShot=True)
        self.__initialMousePos = None
        self.__separator = separator
        self.__placeholderText = placeholderText
        self.setView(QListView())  # Use QListView for the combo box drop-down
        self.__updateItemDelegate()
        self.update_checked_items()  # Ensure the placeholder text is initially set

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        """Reimplemented."""
        self.__popupIsShown = False
        super(CheckComboBox, self).mousePressEvent(event)
        if self.__popupIsShown:
            self.__initialMousePos = event.globalPosition().toPoint()
            self.__blockMouseReleaseTimer.start(QApplication.doubleClickInterval())

    def showPopup(self):
        """Reimplemented."""
        super(CheckComboBox, self).showPopup()
        view = self.view()
        view.installEventFilter(self)
        view.viewport().installEventFilter(self)
        self.__popupIsShown = True

    def hidePopup(self):
        """Reimplemented."""
        self.view().removeEventFilter(self)
        self.view().viewport().removeEventFilter(self)
        self.__popupIsShown = False
        self.__initialMousePos = None
        super(CheckComboBox, self).hidePopup()
        self.view().clearFocus()

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        """Reimplemented."""
        if self.__popupIsShown and event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonRelease:
            model = self.model()
            index = self.view().currentIndex()
            state = model.data(index, Qt.CheckStateRole)
            model.setData(index, Qt.Checked if state == Qt.Unchecked else Qt.Unchecked, Qt.CheckStateRole)
            self.view().update(index)
            self.update_checked_items()  # Update the combo box text when the state changes
            return True
        return super(CheckComboBox, self).eventFilter(obj, event)

    def update_checked_items(self):
        """Update the combo box display with selected items or placeholder text."""
        checked = self.checkedIndices()
        if checked:
            items = [self.itemText(i) for i in checked]
            self.setCurrentText(self.__separator.join(items))
        else:
            self.setCurrentText(self.__placeholderText)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        """Reimplemented."""
        painter = QStylePainter(self)
        option = QStyleOptionComboBox()
        self.initStyleOption(option)
        painter.drawComplexControl(QStyle.CC_ComboBox, option)
        checked = self.checkedIndices()
        if checked:
            items = [self.itemText(i) for i in checked]
            option.currentText = self.__separator.join(items)
        else:
            option.currentText = self.__placeholderText
        option.currentIcon = QIcon()
        painter.drawControl(QStyle.CE_ComboBoxLabel, option)

    def itemCheckState(self, index):
        """
        Return the check state for item at `index`.
        """
        state = self.itemData(index, role=Qt.CheckStateRole)
        if isinstance(state, int):
            return Qt.CheckState(state)
        return Qt.Unchecked

    def setItemCheckState(self, index, state):
        """
        Set the check state for item at `index` to `state`.
        """
        self.setItemData(index, state, Qt.CheckStateRole)

    def checkedIndices(self):
        """
        Return a list of indices of all checked items.
        """
        return [i for i in range(self.count()) if self.itemCheckState(i) == Qt.Checked]

    def setPlaceholderText(self, text):
        """
        Set the placeholder text.
        """
        if self.__placeholderText != text:
            self.__placeholderText = text
            self.update_checked_items()

    def placeholderText(self):
        """
        Return the placeholder text.
        """
        return self.__placeholderText

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        """Reimplemented."""
        event.ignore()

    def __updateItemDelegate(self):
        self.setItemDelegate(CheckComboBox.ComboItemDelegate(self))


def example():
    app = QApplication(list(sys.argv))
    cb = CheckComboBox(placeholderText="Select Me")
    model = cb.model()
    cb.addItem("First")
    cb.setItemCheckState(0, Qt.Unchecked)
    cb.addItem("Second")
    cb.setItemCheckState(1, Qt.Unchecked)
    cb.addItem("Third")
    cb.setItemCheckState(2, Qt.Unchecked)
    cb.show()
    cb.raise_()
    return app.exec()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(example())

Issues I'm Facing:

Overlapping Checkbox and Text: The checkbox is displayed on top of the text, causing visual overlap. I would like the text to appear next to the checkbox without overlap.
Placeholder Not Updating: After selecting items, the combo box placeholder area (display text) is not updating with the selected items. It still shows the placeholder text.

Expected Behavior:

The checkbox should appear next to the item text without overlap.
The placeholder area should update with the selected items once they are checked.

What I Have Tried:

I’ve attempted adjusting the option.rect in the delegate, but it seems the text still overlaps with the checkbox.
I’m using update_checked_items() to update the combo box's text with selected items, but it doesn’t seem to work as expected.

Any suggestions or improvements on how to fix these issues?

I cannot reproduce the overlapping issue, but the placeholder problem is caused by the wrong checking of the checkstate: since Qt6 both PyQt and PySide use actual python Enums, but not all enums are IntEnums, therefore if isinstance(state, int): will fail, and you should check against Qt.CheckState too: if isinstance(state, (int, Qt.CheckState)):. Note that your attempt in checking for mouse events is ineffective (for instance, it automatically "clicks" the item under the mouse). Check the duplicated post to see a more appropriate implementation that properly considers object structure.

thanks its fixed the placeholder issue. i will check the duplicated post to know more about its implementation

btw, is the overlapping issue can be due to the python version i am using as you cant reproduce it with the same code?

As far as I can see, you're just changing the option.rect geometry and then calling the base implementation, which would revert to the underlying Qt functions called by the binding (remember, PyQt and PySide are just Python bindings, they don't do any "Qt" thing, nor the underlying Qt library knows anything about being used from Python). It's more likely that it's caused by the OS/style combination you're using. It may be a bug, but we can't tell more unless you clarify your environment, specifically, OS and Qt versions, and the output of QApplication.style().objectName().

application style is windows11, and the qt version i am using is 6.7.2

I cannot test on modern windows machines, so I can only suggest you to do some attempts with different Qt versions: for instance, I know for a fact that Qt introduced the new "windows11" style in 6.7, which already has some reported issues about item views, so you may check with 6.6 (6.6.3 should be the last in that branch AFAIR) and 6.7.3 as soon as it's available (or you're able to test it from the dev repos). Further testing could be done with a more simple QListView with the same delegate class, but using the same model of the combo.

sure, i will try that. thanks :)

well downgrading qt to 6.6.3 worked. thanks a lot!

You're welcome. I then suggest you to do further tests and verify if the issue also exists with a basic QListView (or other views) with the same delegate implementation or, otherwise, reduce the code to the overlapping problem only, then file a report with it on bugreports.qt.io (with the QTBUG tag, not the PYSIDE one!), with the appropriate env info. If you're able to make a C++ example that would be even better.

I'll try it. :)
